# Windows 10 minimizes program when I call set it to On Top

Tags: vb6, windows-10

This WORKS as expected on two Windows 10 systems (on a VM, the other a live PC). But on a third system (customer's, unfortunately) the form *minimizes* rather than being topmost.

```
SetwindowPos (TargetForm.hwnd, HWND_TOP,0,0,0,0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE)
```

the Form (window) *minimizes*.

Any idea what would cause that?

This is a VB6 program (don't laugh!, I make a living on this program :)

UPDATE:

More details on code:

```
Set FormActive = frmToShow
frmToShow.Show
FormZorderSet frmToShow, Z_top

If Not frmPrevious Is Nothing Then
frmPrevious.Hide
End If

Public Function FormZorderSet(frmTarget As Form, Zorder As FormZorderType) As Long

    FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
    FormZorderSet = SetWindowPos(frmTarget.hwnd, Zorder, 0, 0, 0, 0, FLAGS)
```

Global declares

```
  Public Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
   Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
   Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
   Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
   Const  HWND_TOP = 0
```

Comment: Show us `SetwindowPos` API declare and `HWND_TOPMOST`, `SWP_NOMOVE` & `SWP_NOSIZE` values, please

Answer (score 0):

Try using this ontop function

```
'moudle code
  Option Explicit
  Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = 2
  Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = 1
  Public Const FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
  Public Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
  Public Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2

  Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
        ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
        ByVal x As Long, _
        ByVal y As Long, _
        ByVal cx As Long, _
        ByVal cy As Long, _
        ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

  Public Function SetTopMostWindow(hwnd As Long, Topmost As Boolean) _
     As Long

     If Topmost = True Then 'Make the window topmost
        SetTopMostWindow = SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, _
           0, FLAGS)
     Else
        SetTopMostWindow = SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, _
           0, 0, FLAGS)
        SetTopMostWindow = False
     End If
  End Function
```

Then for the use

```
'use
Dim lR As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'set form to allways on top
lR = SetTopMostWindow(Me.hwnd, True)
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
End Sub
```

This has worked for me in windows 10 without it minimizing my program.

Comment: You can use a timer to make sure it stays on top

Comment: Look closer. That's the same function I"m using.  And remember, my function DOES work on Windows 10. It's just on ONE Windows 10 PC that it doesn't work right.